# What does equipartition of energy tell and why didn't it fit to black body radiation?

Tags: thermal-radiation

What does Equipartition theorem say about energy distribution? And why early physicists did apply the same principle to the heating bodies and what went wrong?
I don't know what "degree of freedom" means for instance.

Why did they relate the molecules to EM waves to use Equipartition theorem? Is there a way to explain these historical period and motivation in an easy way?

Answer (score 3):

> What does Equipartition theorem say about energy distribution?

It says that, if you have a container of gas molecules,  the internal energy of the system will be divided equally between the different **quadratic** (squared) degrees of freedom available.

> I don't know what "degree of freedom" means for instance.

A degree of freedom is any  way the gas molecule can use its energy, it can move, or rotate or  vibrate.

These are $(1/2)mv_x^2$, $(1/2)mv_y^2$, $(1/2)mv_z^2$ for linear momentum.

For rotation these are $(1/2)I\omega_x^2$, $(1/2)I\omega_y^2$, $(1/2)I\omega_z^2$, which involves moments of inertia.

For vibration,  they are $(1/2)k_sx^2$, etc, where $k$ is the "spring constant".

[image]

Image Source: [Molecular Degrees of Freedom](http://www.kshitij-iitjee.com/molar-specific-heat-of-a-solid)

So at relatively low temperatures, the energy of the molecules, (by hitting off of each other) will mean they eventually have the same amount of energy as they travel  between the 3 different basic directions, $V_x$, $V_y$ and $V_z$. The energy gets shared equally, given enough time.

As the temperature increases, they begin to rotate about their axis, the $V_x$, $V_y$ and $V_z$ axis. Except for diatomic molecules, like $O_2$, which only have two axis of rotation.

Then as the temperature increases even more and the molecules bounce off of each other  harder, the bonds between the atoms vibrate, like the tiny springs and masses of a harmonic oscillator.

[image]

Image Source: [University of Manchester](http://theory.physics.manchester.ac.uk/~judith/stat_therm/node81.html)

This chart shows you how the temperature affects the way in which the internal energy of the system is divided.

> And why early physicists did apply the same principle to the heating bodies and what went wrong? Why did they relate the molecules to EM waves to use Equipartition theorem? Is there a way to explain these historical period and motivation in an easy way?

Early physicists assumed that energy was continuous, rather than coming in tiny, seperate packets. You have to remember, at the time, in the 1890's, a lot of physicists did not even believe in atoms. So you don't believe in the equipartition theory either.

So if you assume energy is not exchanged in packets, you are in trouble, because then that implies that an infinite number of  electromagnetic  wave frequencies will exist inside  a black body, (a container that could be raised to a certain temperature and constantly kept at that temperature). An infinite number of waves in turn implies an infinite amount of energy, which is nonsense.

By introducing the idea that energy is exchanged in little, indivisible packets, you can avoid the disaster of expecting infinite energy coming from a black body, by saying that only certain wave frequencies can exist, and that the energy should then be finite, as illustrated in the chart below,

[image]

Image Source: [Black Body Radiation](http://quantumfreak.com/introduction-to-blackbody-radiation/)

Comment: I don't get this part "So if you assume energy is not exchanged in packets, you are in trouble, because then that implies that an infinite number of electromagnetic wave frequencies will exist inside a black body," Where does this infinity come from?

Comment: Well, you have to remember that the old guys had a few things to worry about at the same time, which confused them. 1. Most of them didn't believe in atoms, so the equipartion idea was out the window. 2.    Say you have a long washing line, and you shake it up and down and waves go along it. You can do this shaking faster and faster and get more and more (smaller) waves going on the line. Smaller waves is higher frequency, which is more energy. If energy had no quantum packets, you can have, in fact you **must** have, an infinite number of waves.

Comment: So heating the bb to 1000 degrees implied that you should have an infinite number of waves = infinite energy. But nobody gets infinite energy from 1000 degrees. Planck did not believe in atoms, but he know something drastic was needed, so he came up with the idea that energy only came in packets, so in between the packets no waves, so infinity is gone as now you only are allowed a certain number of waves.

Comment: so they thought infinite number of waves with all of them with different frequencies? I still dont get this part

Comment: Yes, exactly,  you have it spot on there...an infinite number of waves, **ALL WITH DIFFERENT FREQUENCIES** is what I should have said, i am sorry i did not stress that.. This means there is no stopping the higher frequencies being much greater in number, and each one gives off more energy than the last one so you get to stupid amounts of energy in no time from 1000 degrees. They called it the ultraviolet catastrophe, because they could not see why it should not be happening in real life. But oviously it wasn't,  so obviously most waves were not there. look at the curve on the colored chart